# Create a layered panel when validation fails

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-validate, styling

I would like to create a layer with the validation errors and show it like a tooltip side by side with my form. Something like the following sample:

```
+-------------+
|             |
|             |    Normal Form
|             |
+-------------+

+-------------+-----+
|             |     |
|             |-----+    Form with visible 
|             |          validation errors
+-------------+
```

Is it clear? The error container would be only visible if there are validation errors and should be positioned around the top-right area of the form itself.

Actually I have the following sample markup:

```
<form id="information" method="post" action="#">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Please enter your contact details</legend>
          <div id="id">
              <label for="name">Name: (*)</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" class="details" name="name" maxlength="50" title="Insert your Name" />
          </div>
          <div id="id">
              <label for="email">Email: (*)</label>
              <input type="text" id="email" class="details" name="email" maxlength="50" title="Insert your Email" />
          </div>
   </fieldset>
   <div id="submission">
       <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" name="send"/>
   </div>
</form>
```

And this jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var form = $('#information');
    var container = $('<div class="error"><p>Errors:</p><ol></ol></div>').appendTo(form).hide();
    var validator = form.validate({
        errorContainer: container,
        errorLabelContainer: $("ol", container),
        wrapper: 'li',
        meta: "validate"
    });
});
```

which works pretty good to append the error list at below the form. 
How can I show the error div layered on top of the form?

Thanks for helping

Comment: Either add a container to hold the `<fieldset>` and `<div id="submission">` and increase the width of the form, or create a container around the form that's the width of the form+the error container and append the error div to that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your solutions are clear to me but maybe I was not so clear. I mean a layered panel, independent from the form, but just "tied", on its position, to the top-right position of the form itself. I already have a container, that sometimes is a jquery dialog.

Comment: If I understand correctly... What happens if you style `.error` with `position:absolute; top:0; right:0;`?

Comment: I have tried adding styling inline with `.css({ position: absolute, top: 0, right: 0})` and the result is that the error is'nt anymore showed and validation does not work, as it does not prevent submission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By explicitly setting the error message container with an ID and also setting the label container, it is much easier to style the error message box as necessary.

```
<div id="formColumn">
    <form id="information" method="post" action="#">
   <fieldset>
      <legend>Please enter your details</legend>
          <div id="id">
              <label for="name">Name: (*)</label>
              <input type="text" id="name" class="details required" name="name" maxlength="50" title="Insert your Name" />
          </div>
          <div id="id">
              <label for="email">Email: (*)</label>
              <input type="text" id="email" class="details required" name="email" maxlength="50" title="Insert your Email" />
          </div>
   </fieldset>
   <div id="submission">
       <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Send" name="send"/>
   </div>
</form>
</div>
<div id="messageBox"><p>Errors:</p><ol></ol></div>​
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    var form = $('#information');
    var validator = form.validate({
        errorContainer: "#messageBox",
        errorLabelContainer: "#messageBox ol",
        wrapper: 'li',
        meta: "validate"
    });
});
```

CSS:

```
#formColumn{
    display:inline;
    float:left
}
#messageBox{
    display:none;
    float:left
}​
```

Also, be cautious with the class "error" as your contained error message in that the validator plugin uses this name in other places.

http://jsfiddle.net/yvxRc/